# CRUD operations using WordPress database API

Tags: database, query, mysql

What is the correct way to query a WordPress database?

I would like to achieve a similar output as seen in the *links* section of WordPress Dashboard so as to be able to perform *edit* and *delete* operations on given table rows / columns, individually.

I've made use of knowledge drown from several articles on setting up database tables in WordPress and as such was able to build the front-end so as to accommodate both *edit* and *delete* operations; what I currently need is a solid example of how to make use of the WordPress database query API in order to perform all CRUD operations.

Comment: use `wpdb` to query database, read more about it in codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Thanks Eugene, the codex has definitely helped, I guess it's difficult for me because I need the query to return results into a table format, so I'm stumped. In other words, how can I format the query to output results in a table format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querying in WordPress is done by using the the `wpdb` variable. Be sure to always prepare your sql so WP can make it database safe.

Example:

```
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}TABLE_NAME` WHERE `var` = %d", 1) );
```

Then you can loop through the data and output it as for example a table (table formatting not included).

```
foreach($rows as $row) 
{
  echo $row->post_title;
}
```

Please note that the SQL query above doesn't work because it contains dummy data. Please change it so it fits your needs.

Comment: OK, Barry the idea makes sense......so `echo $row->post_title;` would take care of the row display only, or would that also display the columns as I need?

Comment: The `echo $row->post_title;` would only display the title of the post. If you would like to display a row with a single column that would display the title, you can do `echo "<tr><td>{$row->post_title}</td></tr>\n";`.